# Get lists from sharepoint online site using C# code

Tags: c#, list, console-application, sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to connect and retrieve all the list names in the site using a c# code. Different errors occurs. Is there any suggestion to make this work.'

I attached my code which is gives username is not matched error

Thanks.

Here attached the one of code I tried.

```
using System.Security;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using System.Net;

using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://url"))
{
    const string userName = "name@domain.com.au";
            const string password = "password";
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);




    // Get the SharePoint web
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    List targetList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TESTACARD");
    CamlQuery oQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();

    ListItemCollection oCollection = targetList.GetItems(oQuery);
    clientContext.Load(oCollection);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (ListItem oItem in oCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(oItem["Title"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: If it does work sometimes and sometimes not, I have noticed that Sharepoint will randomly error if the server does not have enough memory available. Just something to look out for as well.

Comment: This will lead to an error. can you suggest any code that works. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried limiting the list size: CamlQuery oQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(200);

Comment: No. I dont have a idea about it. I didnt try it.